# Unity 3d : How can I stop the "speeding process" when I jump?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a slight problem in my script with jumping. 
My character basically always moves forward (via rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.Forward * Speed), also, this is being called on Update(). 
The problem is, when I jump, the character keeps moving forward and after some time in air he speeds up due to not colliding with anything and makes the jump unnatural and fake.

How can I stop this "speeding process" when I jump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A force causes an acceleration, meaning your velocity will be constantly increasing.

It sounds like what you're really after is to set the velocity:

```
rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.Forward * Speed;
```

or

```
rigidBody.AddForce(Vector3.Forward * Speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Comment: Hello BlueRaja,
Both scripts worked like a charm but the second one was the one I was looking for. 

Thanks for answering, have a good one!